# KIF: Simulator launches but app doesn't appear, steps time out after 10 seconds

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/

However when I run Product -> Test, the simulator launches but the app does not appear. I made sure that both the "Bundle Loader" and "Test Host" were set correctly. Specifically I set:

"Bundle Loader" to be $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/My App.app/My App

"Test Host" to be $(BUNDLE_LOADER)

I used pods to integrate KIF. To my podfile I added

```
target 'My App Tests', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'KIF', '~> 3.0'
end
```

and ran pod update.

Anyone have any suggestions on what might be happening?

Comment: I was getting immediate failure to 'finish running tests' because my compiler was set to 'unknown' in the testing target. Once I changed it to Apple LLVM (Build settings -> Build Options -> Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C) it worked for me

Comment: Actually, sometimes KIF runs with a black screen but still performs. Are you sure your code isn't executing properly? The time out could be from it legitimately not finding an accessibility label you're giving it.